# Drupal 7 webform

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

Good Morning.
I'm working on a website built with drupal 7 made by another person.
I'm trying to change the url of a page where there is a webform. If i do it, the page is still there with the new url, but the webform disappears. How can I avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That webform probably was set as block to be displayed on certain page URLs only.
You can check in the block section (admin/structure/block), if that webform exist, click configure and see the "Visibility settings" at the bottom. You can change the restricted URL in that settings to "node/[nid]" format instead of the friendly URL so it will still work if you change the URL again in the future.

Comment: Thanks i've been able to edit it. Just another thing. How can i change the address that send the email of the webform?

Comment: You need to find the webform that you want to update, on the edit page go to the Webform tab and then go to E-mails. You should see the list of the emails that being sent by that webform and edit it to change the sender address.